# Apriori Algorithm- frequent item set generation

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, apriori

I am using Apriori algorithm to identify the frequent item sets of the customer.Based on the identified frequent item sets I want to prompt suggest items to customer when customer adds a new item to his shopping list, As the frequent item sets I got the result as follows;

```
[1],[3],[2],[5]
[2.3],[3,5],[1,3],[2,5]
[2,3,5]
```

My problem is if I consider only [2,3,5] set to make suggestions to customer am I wrong? i.e If customer adds item 3 to his shopping list I would recommend item 2 and item 5. If customer adds item 1 to the shopping list no suggestions will be made since I am considering only set [2,3,5] and item 1 is not available in that set. I want to know whether my logic (considering only set [2,3,5]) is enough to make suggestions for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Deriving recommendation rules requires more effort.

Just because [2,3,5] is frequent does *not* mean 2 -> 3,5 is a good rule.

Consider the case that 2 is a very popular product, but 3,5 are just barely frequent. Consider a gas station.  [gas, coffee, bagel] is probably a frequent itemset, but rather few customers who buy gas will also buy coffee and a bagel (low confidence).

You *do* want to consider rules such as 2,3 -> 5 because they may have **higher confidence**. I.e. if the customer buys gas and coffee, suggest a bagel.

**Frequency is not sufficient for recommendations!** Consider 2 and 3 are bought in 80% of cases. 2, 3, 5 is bought in 60% of cases. Naively, in 6 out of 8 times, the customer will also buy 5, that's 75% correct! But this does *not* mean 5 is a good recommendation! Because  5 could be in 80% total, so if he bought 2 and 3, he is actually 5% less likely to buy 5, and we have a negative correlation here. That's why **you need to look at lift, too**. Or other measures like it, there are many.

Comment: I am doing this per customer basis. That means [2,3,5] is frequent only to that particular customer and he frequently buys item 2,3,5 together. In that case can I only consider [2,3,5] set to make suggestions

Comment: No, you cannot. Same example still holds.

Comment: Thanks.. Then that means if the customer has already added item 2 and item 5, I can suggest him item 3 based on [2,3,5] set. now my approach correct?

Comment: Even then, if it is frequent that doesn't yet mean it's *unexpected*. You really need to look at confidence and lift. What you want to answer is this question: Is the customer *more likely* to buy 3 if he already has added 2 and 5. It's not obviousy, but it *can* be frequent but negatively correlated. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should base on how the frequency of the item set is relative to its sub item  sets to figure out the rule. For example

1. if frequency of (2,3,5) is close to the frequency of (3,5), the rule will be (3,5) -> 2
2. If frequency of (2,3,5) is close to the frequency of (3), the rule will be 3 -> (2,5)
3. If frequency of (2,3) is close to the frequency of (2), the rule will be 2 -> 3

That means not only largest frequent item set could be used to make rule but its sub frequent item sets also. And the rule will be more pricise if you could consider how close frequency of item sets is relative to others.

Comment: if user has already added item 2,5 to shopping list and i want to recommend item 3.how the rule should be to recommend item 3 ? i.e frequency of [2,5] should be closer to frequency of [2,3,5] or frequency of [3] should be closer to frequency of [2,3,5]?

Comment: The frequency of (2,5) should be closer to the frequency of (2,3,5). Then the rule is (2,5)-> 3

Comment: don't we need to consider the frequency of [3] ? how frequently customer would like to buy item 3. sometimes even though frequency of [2,5] is closer to frequency of [2,3,5] customer may less likely to buy item 3. In that case we need to consider frequency of [3] as well? could you confirm?

Comment: If you also have frequency of (3) is close to the frequency of (2,3,5) then your rule will be more precise. Then you have more rule to apply i.e (3) -> (2,5). Anyway, no prediction could be exact 100%, but at least you have a reasonale method to follow.

Comment: (2,5) -> 3  means ? could you convert this rule to words please.I am bit confuse

Comment: That means if customer buy 2 and 5, he is likely to buy 3 also

Comment: How you derived the above rules? Could you tell based on what you derived the above rules? is it a pre defined methodology?