# Frequent item set based on Apriori Algorithm and item based recommendation

Tags: algorithm, data-mining, apriori

I am using Apriori Algorithm and Got the following item sets as the frequent item sets when I used min support= 2.(item set : support)
My objective for this implementation is to suggest recommendation to the customer based on his identified frequent item sets and what he has already add to shopping cart

```
-+- L -+-
[5] : 3
[1] : 3
[2] : 3
[3] : 4

-+- L -+-
[1, 2] : 2
[1, 5] : 2
[3, 5] : 3
[1, 3] : 3
[2, 5] : 3
[2, 3] : 3

-+- L -+-
[1, 2, 5] : 2
[1, 2, 3] : 2
[2, 3, 5] : 3
[1, 3, 5] : 2

-+- L -+-
[1, 2, 3, 5] : 2
```

My first question is: I used only support rule to identify the above sets. And at which point I should use confidence and lift rules? Is it when identifying frequent item sets or is it when adding recommendations based on identified frequent item sets?

My second question is: I am using confidence rule when adding recommendation how should I check the confidence rule?
e.g If user added item 2,5 to his shopping list I would recommend to buy item 3 as well.based on [2,3,5] set.To recommend item 3 how the rule should be? i.e **frequency of [2,5] should be closer to frequency of [2,3,5]** or **frequency of [3] should be closer to frequency of [2,3,5]?**

Which condition I must check before suggesting item 3?

My third question is in which situations lift rule will be important? According to the above item set it seems any item can be suggested even though I considered all support,confidence and lift rules. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apriori Algorithm- frequent item set generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351704/apriori-algorithm-frequent-item-set-generation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To one and two:**


Association rules look like:

```
{3} -> {2, 5}
```

Which means for example, if a customer buys 3, he buys with a certain probability 2 and 5 too. Again, the probability is determined by the support and confidence. For instance:

```
> dataset 
1: {1, 2, 3} 
2: {1, 2, 4}
3: {1, 2, 5} 

Support level = 0.6
Confidence level = 0.6
Number of cases = 3

// Get frequency of each item
Total number of 1's bought = 3
Total number of 2's bought = 3
Total number of 3's bought = 1
Total number of 4's bought = 1
Total number of 5's bought = 1

// Check support of each item against support level
Support of 1 = 3 / 3 = 1 >= 0.6 = support level
Support of 2 = 3 / 3 = 1 >= 0.6 = support level
Support of 3 = 1 / 3 = 0.33 <= 0.6 = support level
Support of 4 = 1 / 3 = 0.33 <= 0.6 = support level
Support of 5 = 1 / 3 = 0.33 <= 0.6 = support level
-> Frequent itemsets = {(1), (2), (1, 2)}
-> Association rules = {1 -> 2}

// Check confidence of each association rule against confidence level
Confidence of 1 -> 2 = 3 / 3 = 1 >= 0.6 = confidence level
-> Strong association rules = {1 -> 2}
-> For a customer who buys 1, the recommandation is article 2
```

**To three:**


The provided data are frequent itemsets and no association rules. Therefore, from those raw frequent itemsets it's not possible to associate suggestions like if a customer buys 1 he is going to buy 2 too with a certain probability. They need to be processed to association rules. And a lift value just indicates for an association rule in which relation the confidence value of the association rule stays with the expected value. In other words the meaningfulness of this association rule.


Hope this helps.

Comment: In your answer you have identified frequent item sets as {(1), (2), (1, 2)} and in the next line you have derived Association rules = {1 -> 2}. how did you get it at once. In my case there are many frequent item sets and how can I find association rule?

Comment: According to my observation if we build the association rule using the items in the frequent item set and find the confidence it is always strong.Therefor no need of finding confidence.please give me your ophinion

Comment: To one: Association rules can be generated from n + 1 frequent itemsets, e.g. {1, 2, 3} has {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}} as subsets. Therefore, {{{1} -> {2, 3}}, {{2} -> {1, 3}}, {{3} -> {1, 2}}, {{2, 3} -> {1}}, {{1, 3} -> {2}}, {{1, 2} -> 3}} are association rules. To two: An association rule is only strong if the frequency of the occurences in the datasets of the first part of the association rule divided by the frequency of the occurences of the second part of the association rule in those datasets where the first part has occured is over the confidence.

Answer (score 0):

You have done only the first step, **frequent itemsets**.

Frequent itemsets look like this: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and have a *support*.

Now you need to do the second step, **association rules**.

You want rules that look like this:

```
1, 2, 3 -> 4, 5  (confidence: 60%, lift: 1.2)
```

Which say "if a user has 1, 2 and 3 in their basket then recommend 4 and 5. You *then* compute confidence and lift to decide which rules to keep and use.

Comment: yes based on higher confidence and lift values I may recommend some item/items to customer. To find which item/item sets have higher confidence/lift value with the items in the basket do I need to go through the all possible item sets in the supermarket item list and find the confidence and lift values which will be more suitable to suggest to the user?

Comment: If there is more than one rule applicable, that is yet another question (albeit mostly an UI decision).